# How to use Prepend_WWW in DJango

Tags: django, dns, pythonanywhere

I am facing issues in a project, my site opens with www, but doesn't load if that part is missing. 

I read about **PREPEND_WWW= True** (since if user types just domain, redirect to www.domain.com which works) in **settings.py** on django, but that just doesn't work.

I have enabled CommonMiddleware too.

Any other thing that can be done to solve?.

Please help

Comment: Did you enable [CommonMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#prepend-www)?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I see you've tagged your question with PythonAnywhere -- if you are indeed using the PythonAnywhere hosting system, then this [help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/NakedDomains) will explain how to set things up so that requests to `yourdomain.com` are automatically forwarded to `www.yourdomain.com`.